# I want to make the success notification and error notification fade after 4 seconds after the notification but have tried doing it not working.

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $("#ajaxform").submit(function(e){
        var contactdata  =  $(this).serializeArray();
        var submiturl    =  $(this).attr('action');
        var submitbtn    =  $('#submit');
        submitbtn.val('Sending...');
        $("#ajaxform :input").prop("disabled", true);
          $.ajax({
            url: submiturl,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            data : contactdata,
            success: function(response){
               $('#alert').removeClass('alert alert-success');
               $('#alert').removeClass('alert alert-danger');
               if(response.status=="true"){
                $('#alert').addClass('alert alert-success');
                $("#ajaxform :input").prop("disabled", false);
                $('#ajaxform')[0].reset();
                submitbtn.val('Send');
               }else{
                $("#alert").addClass('alert alert-danger');
                $("#ajaxform :input").prop("disabled", false);
                submitbtn.val('Send');
               }
               $('#alert').html(response.message).slideDown();
            }
          });
        e.preventDefault(); 
    }); 
});
```

I want to make the success notification and error notification fade after 4 seconds after the notification but have tried doing it not working. Am new in coding javascript

Comment: What does happen after you run the code? Let me guess: the #alert slides down immediately instead of after 4 seconds.

Comment: it just show the success box and doesnt fade or disappear

Answer (score 0):

This part shows the alert:

```
$('#alert').html(response.message).slideDown();
```

The code hiding the alert after 4 seconds is missing. You would put it after the code showing the alert. For example:

```
setTimeout(function() { $('#alert').hide(); }, 4000);
```

Link to documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

Comment: So i should replace 
               $('#alert').html(response.message).slideDown();
with 
        setTimeout(function() { $('#alert').hide(); }, 4000);

Comment: No, you should have both lines one after another :)